# Reverse range-like functionality in php arrays

Tags: php, arrays, numbers, range, reverse

I have an array like this:

```
array(0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99);
```

and I want to get it as a the following string:

`0, 2, 4-7, 90+`

Any examples out there before I start to pull hairs from my head ?
Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
Here is the final solution I used after taking @Andy's code, and modifying it a bit.

```
function rangeArrayToString($rangeArray, $max = 99) {
    sort($rangeArray);
    $first = $last = null;
    $output = array();

    foreach ($rangeArray as $item) {
        if ($first === null) {
            $first = $last = $item;
        } else if ($last < $item - 1) {
            $output[] = $first == $last ? $first : $first . '-' . $last;
            $first = $last = $item;
        } else {
            $last = $item;
        }
    }

    $finalAddition = $first;

    if ($first != $last) {
        if ($last == $max) {
            $finalAddition .= '+';
        } else {
            $finalAddition .= '-' . $last;
        }
    }

    $output[] = $finalAddition;

    $output = implode(', ', $output);
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Erm... Maybe you should try to use some *programming* to solve this? I'm not trying to offend you, but this is a simple task if you use your brain a little.

Comment: I really don't understand how still there are people who comment comments like you just did, in sites made for users to ask questions.
If you think it's a no brainer, you don't have to answer this question, but telling me I can try to do it by programming, isn't helping at all. I like seeing code examples. It enriches my coding practices by not sticking in to paradigms.

Comment: This site is for when you have trouble with code, not for when you don't want to do the coding yourself and would prefer to have someone else do it for you. If you would have posted something you tried and didn't work it would have been something completely different.

Comment: @Alin, you're welcome to see my other questions if you think I wanted someone else to do my job.

Comment: Why was this question edited to include "the final solution"?  ...that's what answers are for.  This question looks like a good candidate for "Needs More Focus".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$first = $last = null;
$output = array();

foreach ($array as $item) {
    if ($first === null) {
        $first = $last = $item;
    } else if ($last < $item - 1) {
        $output[] = $first == $last ? $first : $first . '-' . $last;
        $first = $last = $item;
    } else {
        $last = $item;
    }
}

$output[] = $first == $last ? $first : $first . '+';
$output = join(', ', $output);
```

Comment: of course that's assuming the array is sorted, otherwise asort() the array first

Comment: Thanks @Andy.
Your code assumed the last number in the given array is the maximum possible (for the + sign). I added a $max variable to set that, so it will only add the + sign if the count continues to the maximum number. See my code in my original questions.

Comment: +1 I'm relieved to see that my own homegrown version is essentially the same as this. But your's is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

```
function makeRange($array, $last=array(), $done=array()){
    if ($array == array()) {
        return $done;
    }

    $h = $array[0]; 
    $t = array_slice($array, 1);

    if ($last == array()) {
        $last = array($array[0], $array[0]);
    }
    if ($t[0] == 1 + $last[1]) {
        return makeRange($t, array($last[0], $h+1), $done);
    }
    $done[] = $last;
    return makeRange($t, array(), $done);
}

print_r(makeRange(array(1,2,3,5,6,7, 9, 11,12,13,18)));

// Output 

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 7
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => 9
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11
            [1] => 13
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 18
            [1] => 18
        )

)
```

you could add a simple decorator to give the required 4-7 instead of array(4,7). This I left out because the view of the data should be seperate.

Hope that helps.